# How to create a new array based on a condition from 2 arrays?

Tags: python, arrays

I have two corresponding arrays

```
x = ['30', '67', '25.6', '15', '23', '78']
y = ['success', 'fail', 'success', 'live', 'fail', 'success']
```

I'm trying to create an if statement or definition to change the x array for satisfying the y array of the condition 'success' such that my new x array would be

```
new_x = ['30', '25.6', '78']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print([a for a,b in zip(x,y) if b == 'success'])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple and clean solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` to loop over the values in a collection and also keep track of the current position.

```
x = ['30', '67', '25.6', '15', '23', '78']
y = ['success', 'fail', 'success', 'live', 'fail', 'success']

new_x = []

for position, word in enumerate(y):
    if word == 'success':
        new_x.append(x[position])
```